# How to get previous variable value on React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have a variable that is already setup from the API result, the value is an array:

```
tier_items = [{id:1, name:'coffee'}, {id:2, name:'tea'}, {id:2, name:'juice'}]
```

this `tier_items` value is always updated with this condition

```
useEffect(()=>{console.log('tier_items')}, [tier_items])
```

value after updated : `tier_items = [{id:1, name:'coffee'}]`

I need to get both the previous & current value of updated `tier_items`

```
const [current, setCurrent] = useState(tier_items) 
const [previous, setPrevious] = ???
```

this is the expected result

`current = [{id:1, name:'coffee'}]`

`previous = [{id:1, name:'coffee'}, {id:2, name:'tea'}, {id:2, name:'juice'}]`

also the next upcoming value onwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must update previous when updating current, for example :

```
setCurrent((current) => {
    setPrevious((currentPrevious) => return [...current, ...currentPrevious])
    return [{id:1, name:'coffee'}];
}
```

That should do what you want :)

Comment: thanks for the solution @Elley!
the result looks like this
`current = [{id:1, name:'coffee'}]
previous = [[{id:1, name:'coffee'}, {id:2, name:'tea'}, {id:2, name:'juice'}],[]]`

but it's okay I can use `previous[0]`

Comment: Oh, right, current is also an array, see my edited answer :)

Comment: sorry @Elley this one `return [...current, ...currentPrevious] ` makes increment loop for several times : `previous=[{id:1, name:'coffee'}, {id:2, name:'tea'}, {id:2, name:'juice'}, {id:1, name:'coffee'}, {id:2, name:'tea'}, {id:2, name:'juice'}]`

Comment: ... That's weird, what's the content or current and currentPrevious at that moment in the code then ? (when it's first called)

Comment: ... in that moment `current = [{id:1, name:'coffee'}, {id:2, name:'tea'}, {id:2, name:'juice'}]`, and then `currentPrev = []`

Comment: So, after that call, in the useEffect that's watching over current and previous changes, what do you get ?